# How to organize a list of covariance pairs in a squared covariance matrix?

Tags: r, covariance

I am working in R and I have a tibble composed of three columns:

- `V1`: the name of the first variable
- `V2`: the name of the second variable
- `cov`: the value of the covariance between `V1` and `V2`.

This tibble is expanded over `n` columns for `n` covariance pairs.

I would like to get a matrix that looks like a classical covariance matrix, ie a square `n` x `n` matrix with the covariance pairs in it.

Any idea how could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
## find row/column names
n <- unique(c(dd$V1,dd$V2))
## construct matrix  
M <- matrix(NA, length(n),length(n), dimnames=list(n,n))
## fill in values
M[cbind(dd$V1,dd$V2)] <- dd$V3
```

If you only have the lower/upper triangle in your initial data set you'll need something like `M[lower.tri(M)] <- t(M)[upper.tri(M)]` to symmetrize ...

Answer (score 3):

You could construct a sparse matrix:

```
DF <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"), 
                 var2 = c("b", "c", "c", "a", "b", "c"), 
                 cov = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
DF$var1 <- factor(DF$var1, levels = sort(unique(c(DF$var1, DF$var2))))
DF$var2 <- factor(DF$var2, levels = levels(DF$var1))

library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(i = as.integer(DF$var1), 
             j = as.integer(DF$var2), 
             x = DF$cov, 
             dimnames = list(levels(DF$var1), levels(DF$var2)),
             symmetric = TRUE)
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#    a   b   c
#a 0.4 0.1 0.2
#b 0.1 0.5 0.3
#c 0.2 0.3 0.6
```

Use `as.matrix` to create a dense matrix if you need one.